# Converting directory with images to csv file in python

Tags: python, numpy, csv

Im trying to copy the pixel information of a group of images to a CSV, however when I try the following code, Im unable to create the csv. Is there any other way to copy the pixels to a csv?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import csv

# default format can be changed as needed
def createFileList(myDir, format='.png'):
    fileList = []
    print(myDir)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myDir, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(format):
                fullName = os.path.join(root, name)
                fileList.append(fullName)
    return fileList

# load the original image
myFileList = createFileList('/test/surprise')

for file in myFileList:
    print(file)
    img_file = Image.open(file)
    # img_file.show()

    # get original image parameters...
    width, height = img_file.size
    format = img_file.format
    mode = img_file.mode

    # Make image Greyscale
    img_grey = img_file.convert('L')
    #img_grey.save('result.png')
    #img_grey.show()

    # Save Greyscale values
    value = np.asarray(img_grey.getdata(), dtype=np.int).reshape((img_grey.size[1], img_grey.size[0]))
    value = value.flatten()
    print(value)
    with open("imagenes.csv", 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(value)
```

I would like to generate a csv with the pixel information similar to FER2013.csv as can be see in the following image.

[image: FER2013]

Comment: I tried your code and works as expected.. what's the issue ?

Comment: It runs without errors, but I can't find the csv so I think its not being generated. Maybe its because of the Python version. With which version of Python did it work for you?

Comment: Add this to the top, and try looking in that folder: `print(os.getcwd())`